# RabbitMQ .Net Client not adding Jaeger trace context to Headers

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, open-telemetry, jaeger

I have a .Net Class Library project which implements RabbitMQ producers and consumers. I have added `OpenTelemetry/Jaeger` trace context to the message headers but at runtime  when I inspect the message's Headers property it is null.

The tracing context is being generated correctly but it seems ***the trace context, tags as well as baggage are all not being added to the headers***.

This is the publisher code (truncated for brevity) :

```
namespace Rabbit.Comms.Client
{
    public class RpcPublisher : IDisposable
    {
   
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       ...
       ...
    }

     public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion Dispose

    internal Subscriber<BaseResponseMessageContext> Subscriber { get; }
    internal Publisher Publisher { get; }
    internal IModel Channel { get; }
    internal ILogger Logger { get; }
    private bool DisposeChannel { get; } = false;

    private readonly TextMapPropagator Propagator = Propagators.DefaultTextMapPropagator;
    private readonly ActivitySource Activity = new ActivitySource(nameof(Publisher));
    private static string trackId = null;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<BaseResponseMessageContext>> callbackMapper =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<BaseResponseMessageContext>>();

    public RpcPublisher(IConnection connection, string subscriberExchangeName = "amq.direct", ILogger logger = null) : this(connection.CreateModel(), subscriberExchangeName, logger)
    {
        DisposeChannel = true;
    }

    public RpcPublisher(IModel channel, string subscriberExchangeName = "amq.direct", ILogger logger = null)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Channel = channel;
        Channel.BasicReturn += Channel_BasicReturn;
        Publisher = new Publisher(channel);
        Subscriber = new Subscriber<BaseResponseMessageContext>(channel, RabbitMQExtension.GetDefaultSubscriberRoutingKey, ConsumerFunctionAsync, subscriberExchangeName ?? RabbitMQExtension.GetDefaultSubscriberExchangeName, allowCancellation: false, logger: logger);
    }
   ...
   ....

    private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; } = null;

    public async Task<BaseResponseMessageContext> SendAsync(string routingKey, IMessageContext message, int timeoutSec = 0, string exchangeName = "amq.topic", CancellationToken ct = default)
    {

        using (var tracerProvider = TracerProviderFactory.CreateTracerProvider())
        {

            ActivitySource.AddActivityListener(TraceActivityListener.CreateActivityListener());

            using (var activity = Activity.StartActivity("RabbitMq Publish", ActivityKind.Producer))
            {
                //override TrackingId with jaeger TraceId
                trackId = TracerProviderFactory.ConvertToGuidFormat(activity?.TraceId.ToHexString());
                PropertyInfo globalTrackIdProperty = message.GetType().GetProperty("TrackingId");
                if (globalTrackIdProperty != null && globalTrackIdProperty.CanWrite)
                    globalTrackIdProperty.SetValue(message, trackId);
                
                //add trace context to header
                IBasicProperties props = Channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                AddActivityToHeader(activity, props);
                 
                //test with ordinary headers
                //props.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                //props.Headers["Name"] = "Bob";
                //props.Headers["Age"] = 21;

                if (message == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

        string correlationId = RabbitMQExtension.GetCorrelationId();
        if (callbackMapper.ContainsKey(correlationId))
            throw new DuplicateWaitObjectException(nameof(correlationId), $"A message with this correlationId: {correlationId} has already been used. Please generate new ones.");
        try
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<BaseResponseMessageContext> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BaseResponseMessageContext>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
            if (!callbackMapper.TryAdd(correlationId, tcs))
                throw new Exception($"CorrelationId: {correlationId} was not added");

            //setting max timeout
            CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeoutMs(timeoutSec));
           ....
           ....

            Publisher.ReplyTo replyTo = new Publisher.ReplyTo()
            {
                ExchangeName = Subscriber.ExchangeName,
                RoutingKey = Subscriber.RoutingKey
            };

            Logger?.LogDebug("A message with correlationId: {correlationId} will be send. Please reply to {ExchangeName} -> {RoutingKey}", correlationId, replyTo.ExchangeName, replyTo.RoutingKey);

            await Publisher.SendAsync(routingKey, message, exchangeName, correlationId: correlationId, replyTo: replyTo, ct: ct, mandatory: true);

            var test = await tcs.Task;
            timeoutToken.Dispose();
            userToken.Dispose();
            return test;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger?.LogError(ex, "RpcPublisher.SendAsync catch exception with correlationId:{correlationId}", correlationId);
            if (callbackMapper.TryRemove(correlationId, out var tmp))
                tmp.SetException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
         }
       }
    }

    private void AddActivityToHeader(Activity activity, IBasicProperties props)
    {
        Propagator.Inject(new PropagationContext(activity.Context, Baggage.Current), props, InjectContextIntoHeader);
        activity?.SetTag("messaging.system", "rabbitmq");
        activity?.SetTag("messaging.destination_kind", "queue");
        activity?.SetTag("messaging.rabbitmq.queue", "sample");
    }

    private void InjectContextIntoHeader(IBasicProperties props, string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (props.Headers == null)
            {
                props.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            }
            props.Headers[key] = value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation(ex, "Failed to inject trace context.");
        }
    }

}
```

}

The trace context is being picked up successfully:
[image: trace]

but the even after stepping through , either of the context or tags, is available in the headers:

[image: headers]

WHAT I HAVE TRIED

As a test I added the SpanId and TraceId as a pair of custom headers as below:

```
                IBasicProperties props = Channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                // AddActivityToHeader(activity, props);
                props.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                props.Headers.Add("trace-id", activity?.TraceId.ToHexString());
                props.Headers.Add("span-id", activity?.SpanId.ToHexString());
                var check = props;
```

The properties are available in the message BasicProperties header but they are not available at the consumer end:
[image: addheader]

At the consumer end I am retrieving the headers via `BasicDeliverEventArgs ea` but strangely enough the headers are null :

```
                  namespace Rabbit.Comms.Client
{
    public class Subscriber<T> : IDisposable where T : IMessageContext
    {
    #region Dispose
    private bool DisposeChannel { get; } = false;
    private bool disposedValue;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       ...
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
       ...
    }
    public List<string> RoutingKeys { get; }
    public string RoutingKey { get { return RoutingKeys.OrderByDescending(r => r.Length).FirstOrDefault(); } }
    public string ExchangeName { get; }
    internal IModel Channel { get; }
    internal ILogger Logger { get; }

    private static readonly ActivitySource Activity = new ActivitySource("Subscriber");
    private static readonly TextMapPropagator Propagator = new TraceContextPropagator();


    public Subscriber(IConnection connection, string routingKey, Func<T, BasicDeliverEventArgs, CancellationToken, Task> consumerFunction, string subscriberExchangeName = "amq.topic", ushort? prefetchCount = null, bool allowCancellation = true, ILogger logger = null)
        : this(connection, new List<string>() { routingKey }, consumerFunction, subscriberExchangeName, prefetchCount, allowCancellation, logger)
    {
    }
  
    public Subscriber(IModel channel, string routingKey, Func<T, BasicDeliverEventArgs, CancellationToken, Task> consumerFunction, string subscriberExchangeName = "amq.topic", ushort? prefetchCount = null, bool allowCancellation = true, ILogger logger = null)
        : this(channel, new List<string>() { routingKey }, consumerFunction, subscriberExchangeName, prefetchCount, allowCancellation, logger)
    {
    }

    public Subscriber(IConnection connection, List<string> routingKeys, Func<T, BasicDeliverEventArgs, CancellationToken, Task> consumerFunction, string subscriberExchangeName = "amq.topic", ushort? prefetchCount = null, bool allowCancellation = true, ILogger logger = null)
        : this(connection.CreateModel(), routingKeys, consumerFunction, subscriberExchangeName, prefetchCount, allowCancellation, logger)
    {
        DisposeChannel = true;
    }
    public Subscriber(IModel channel, List<string> routingKeys, Func<T, BasicDeliverEventArgs, CancellationToken, Task> consumerFunction, string subscriberExchangeName = "amq.topic", ushort? prefetchCount = null, bool allowCancellation = true, ILogger logger = null)
    {
        ExchangeName = subscriberExchangeName;
        RoutingKeys = routingKeys.Select(rk => RabbitMQExtension.CleanRoutingKey(rk)).ToList();
        string queueName = RoutingKey;
        Channel = channel;

        if (prefetchCount != null)
            Channel.BasicQos(0, prefetchCount.Value, false);

        if (allowCancellation)
            CancelQueue(queueName);

        Channel.CreateQueue(queueName);
        foreach(string route in RoutingKeys)
            Channel.QueueBind(queueName, ExchangeName, route);

        EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(Channel);

        if (Channel.DefaultConsumer == null)
            Channel.DefaultConsumer = consumer;

        consumer.Received += async (object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) =>
        {
            try
            {
               
                var parentContext = Propagator.Extract(default, ea.BasicProperties, ExtractTraceContextFromBasicProperties);
                Baggage.Current = parentContext.Baggage;

                //Start a new Activity
                using (var activity = Activity.StartActivity("Process Message", ActivityKind.Consumer, parentContext.ActivityContext))
                {
                    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    CancellationTokenSource.Add(ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId, cts);
                    T messageData = RabbitMQExtension.DeserializeObject<T>(ea.Body.Span.ToArray());
                    Channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false); 
                    await consumerFunction(messageData, ea, cts.Token);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger?.LogError(ex, "Subscriber.Received ended with exception correlationId:{correlationId}", ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId);
                throw ex;
            }
        };
        Channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
    }

   ...
   ...

    //Extract the Activity from the message header
    public  IEnumerable<string> ExtractTraceContextFromBasicProperties(IBasicProperties props, string key)
    {
        try
        {           
            if (props.Headers.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                var bytes = value as byte[];
                return new[] { Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Logger.LogInformation($"Failed to extract trace context: {ex}");
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    //Add Tags to the Activity
    public static void AddActivityTags(Activity activity)
    {
        activity?.SetTag("messaging.system", "rabbitmq");
        activity?.SetTag("messaging.destination_kind", "queue");
        activity?.SetTag("messaging.rabbitmq.queue", "sample");
    }

}
```

}

I am implementing this based on the example given [here](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/getting-started-with-opentelemetry-and-dotnet-core/)

What am I missing?

Comment: The official example is [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/examples/MicroserviceExample). I'd check for any differences with that code.